# DFA L(n)={a^n b^n : n=0,1,2}

Tags: graph, dfa

How to draw a graph of an automaton that allows language below:

```
L(n)={a^n b^n : n=0,1,2} ?
```

[image: I attach my graph bellow]

Answer (score 0):

You have requested a DFA, so it means that for a given symbol read at a particular state, there is only one destination state, and that symbol can't be an empty string. (Unless you are considering an NFA). It is also a good practice to draw paths for every symbol (or set of symbol) in the alphabet, therefore I have added an arrow for the symbol "a" and an arrow for the symbol "b", even if the destination state is an "hole" just like the state H. Hope it helps.

[image: DFA a^nb^n n<=2]

Comment: Can you tell me what tool you used to make this diagram? It looks good.

Comment: @J...S go to [Finite State Machine Designer](http://madebyevan.com/fsm/)